# I'm wondering why I have to write "private" from SUPER NEW

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm just studying Kotlin about MVP Model.
after I made MainPresenter class, I connected with interface, mainContract
and I faced a problem. I fixed it up but I can't explain it by myself so can you explain why I have to add 'private'?

```
MainPresenter

class mainPresenter : mainContract.Presenter {

private lateinit var mainModel: mainModel

private lateinit var view: mainContract.View
// here's private is that i ask u

override fun setView(view: mainContract.View) {
}

override fun setModel(model: mainModel) {
}

override fun onConfirm() {
}
}

//here is interface

interface mainContract {
interface Presenter {
    fun setView(view: mainContract.View)
    fun setModel(model: mainModel)
    fun onConfirm()

}

interface View {
    fun showButtonText(text: String)
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered here:
https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/private-in-java-why-should-you-always.html

Or even here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables

A short answer: "none of your business how this class works, here is what you have to know". If you are writing a single app, there is no real harm in making everything public. However - if you are writing a library, you might want to keep the same user facing functions, and modify non-user facing functions - internal API.

Comment: isn't it because he has an interface inside an interface...? just wondering lol